# IPPBX with centos 6 server and balancer

Tags: pbx

I have centos6 server runs selta IPPBX and have problem with E1s, all analoug and digital lines and voip are workin well just E1's which are Qsig protocal, if you want the details of the system, please look below, please if any one can help me.

The ippbx, selta brand, It consiste of CentOS6 server and switch and group of pbx's, some of them called ATAs (run the analouge and digital lines), and the other called Truncks (run the E1s).
and one of them called Balancer (like trunck).
each one of these (truncks and ATAs) contain two UC and two DSP-Farm in addition to other cards.
It connect to switch by DSP-Farm and UC, only Balancer connect to server through the UC and to switch through the DSP-Farm.
The centos server has three port (eth), one has the private ip that connect to switch (and all the ATAs and truncks connect to this network), the seconed port has public ip to connect to the other server (redundancy) and the third port has public ip connect to the balancer (uc balancer has public ip and its DSP-Farm has private which connect to switch).

The problem happened when I re-install the server with os (centos6) and the telephony application that was insalled befor the reinstallation, every think done well only the E1's doesn't work?